# Asking a cafe/restaurant if they have Wi-Fi *and* electricity for using a device

Tags: translation, vocabulary

In my travels in China [I've found myself in need of a place to use my internet device](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22014). Its battery has recently ceased to hold a charge so I also need to be able to plug in my AC adaptor.

My Chinese is at a level I describe as "pre embrionic" and my attempts are usually not fully understood. Here are the kinds of things I've been trying:

- Wi-Fi 和 电 有马?
- 无线 和 电 有没有?

I think there are two problems. The minor one is whether to try to use a Chinese or "Universal" (English) term for Internet/Wi-Fi.

The major one is how ask if they have a place with an electric outlet/socket. Literally asking "do you have electricity" does not seem to convey my need.

Comment: For the second problem, you can show them your adaptor.  Body language may be more useful and easy.

Comment: Yes I usually resort to taking off my backpack and digging through it for the adaptor. I'm typically in this situation when arriving fully laden in a new city. Places like KFC and Dico's can be sometimes too crowded to do this.

Comment: I would say `你们这里有无线网和电源插座吗?`

Comment: Just mime plugging in.  People will understand.  Of course it is always good to learn more language.  But these tasks can be done without using any language at all -- and that will work as well in Nepal or Burma.....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually the literal translation of English sounds natural in this case: 你们有Wi-Fi和电源吗？  or 你们有Wi-Fi和插座吗？

Here 电源 means power source, and 插座 means electric socket.

Answer (score 1):

As a Chinese, we usually make it very simple：

请问你们这儿提供无线上网吗？

In fact I think if you wanna know whether a restaurant supports WiFi things such as WiFi devices，you can ask like this below:

请问你们无线路由器有吗？

Sometimes China Mobile will offer some specific WiFi Areas or WiFi USB device, you can also try to ask like this:

请问无线上网区在哪里？

请问无线上网卡（无线上网U盘）有吗？

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of power supply, though.

Comment: Hehe, yes. However power is usually linked with WiFi device such as "无线路由器" or something related to that, as far as I see.

Comment: Really?I Know lots of places that offer WiFi but not power.

Answer (score -1):

You can just pronounce Wi-Fi or Wu(up) Xian(down).
It's "you wifi he dian yuan ma? " or "you wuxian he dian yuan ma?"

Comment: This is what I was trying except without the "yuan". But I think no matter how I try I get all the vowels, all the tones, and perhaps a couple of the consonants wrong. At least something goes wrong ...

Comment: What does Wu(up) Xian(down) mean?